# How am I supposed to create a json oath2 token in .NET 8?

Tags: c#, .net, oauth-2.0, jwt, bearer-token

This code got smashed by the upgrade from .NET 7 to .NET 8 and I'm trying to unsmash it.

It was rather brutal; the normal way to finding these things didn't work; it appears one could continue to import the .NET 7 implementation but that assembly throws.

I have a RSA certificate in a `.PFX` file and I need to sign my client id (which is a long string that doesn't change) and a new guid and thus produce a bearer assertion that converts to an OAuth token via an https call.

What we have here is something that starts with the .NET code and suddenly switches in the middle to .NET 7 and doesn't work. All the useful articles are still for .NET 7. Oof.

```
var rsaPrivateKey = cert.GetRSAPrivateKey();

var privateSecurityKey = new RsaSecurityKey(rsaPrivateKey);
var now = DateTime.UtcNow;

var handler = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.JsonWebTokenHandler();

#if notdef // Seam
var claims = new[] {
    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, clientId),
    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
};

var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

var token = new JwtSecurityToken(clientId,
                    GetUrl("oauth2/token"),
                    claims,
                    now.AddMilliseconds(-30),
                    now.AddMinutes(5),
                    new SigningCredentials(privateSecurityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha384)
                 );
#endif
// end seam here?

var clientAssert = handler.WriteToken(token);

// or is it here?
var searchParams = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "grant_type", "client_credentials" },
            { "client_assertion_type" , "urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer" },
            { "client_assertion" ,  clientAssert }
        };

using var response = await client.PostAsync(GetUrl("oauth2/token"), new FormUrlEncodedContent(searchParams));
```

where `GetUrl` just gets the site-specific install base.

I'm not sure where to go from here. It is unlikely that rebuilding the OAuth library from cryptographic primitives is wise.

Answer (score 0):

I've adjusted my previous solution following your original code.

Basically, my update allows for a more unified approach to token creation and token signing by utilising the `JwtSecurityTokenHandler` and SecurityTokenDescriptor. following this approach, we have code that uses `JwtSecurityTokenHandler` thus enabling compatibility between both .NET 7 and .NET 8.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

// ... (Add any other necessary code parts, like class definition, etc.)

var cert = /* Load your certificate */;
var rsaPrivateKey = cert.GetRSAPrivateKey();
var privateSecurityKey = new RsaSecurityKey(rsaPrivateKey);
var now = DateTime.UtcNow;

var claims = new[] {
    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, clientId),
    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
};

var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
{
    Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
    Expires = now.AddMinutes(5),
    SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(privateSecurityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha384),
    IssuedAt = now
};

var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
var securityToken = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
var clientAssert = tokenHandler.WriteToken(securityToken);

var searchParams = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "grant_type", "client_credentials" },
    { "client_assertion_type", "urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer" },
    { "client_assertion", clientAssert }
};

using var client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.PostAsync(GetUrl("oauth2/token"), new FormUrlEncodedContent(searchParams));
```

Comment: Actually you didn't and this code can't compile. `JwtRegisteredClaimNames` doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: See, I've not got enough context, so my solution was more of a guide in the hopes of leading you to a different solve or, perhaps, sparking the missing puzzle piece?


So based on your question, I believe you said, "This code got smashed by the upgrade from .NET 7 to .NET 8 and I'm trying to un-smash it."


My question is. Are you using some kind of version control? if so, surely, you're able to rollback to a working version, then, you should be able to update the deprecations as well as test potential problematic code?

Comment: I have version control; rolling back to a working version means rolling back to .NET 7. There are no deprecation warnings; it just throws on run.

Comment: Anyway; as far as I can tell, this approach is completely wrong and you definitely didn't try it at all.